# cant delete file after programmatically creation

Tags: c#

i have a problem to delete a file that i have created programmatically before but i dont understand what is the problem, i have closed the streams but it say that this file is already in use in a process..

the line where is the error is:

```
System.IO.File.Delete(@"c:\Invoice - " + invoiceid + ".pdf");
```

the code is:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            button1.Hide();
            button2.Hide();
            var frm = Form.ActiveForm;
            var bmp = new Bitmap(frm.Width, frm.Height);
            frm.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height));
            bmp.Save(@"c:\image.png");

            FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"c:\image - " + documentid + ".pdf", FileMode.Create);
            Document pdfdoc = new Document();
            PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfdoc, fs);
            pdfdoc.Open();
            iTextSharp.text.Image img = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(bmp, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            img.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
            img.ScaleToFit(500f, 800f);

            pdfdoc.Add(img);
            pdfdoc.Close();
            fs.Close();
            try
            {
                MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
                SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient(dataSmtp, 587);
                mail.From = new MailAddress(dataAddress);
                mail.To.Add(email.ToString());
                mail.To.Add("some text");
                mail.Bcc.Add("some text");
                mail.Subject = "doc "+ documentid;
                mail.Body = "some text";

                Attachment attachment = new Attachment(@"c:\image - "+ documentid +".pdf");
                mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);

                SmtpServer.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(dataAddress, dataPsw);
                SmtpServer.EnableSsl = false;

                SmtpServer.Send(mail);
                
                MessageBox.Show("sent correctly!", "sent!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex, "Error!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            System.IO.File.Delete(@"c:\image.png");
            System.IO.File.Delete(@"c:\image - " + documentid + ".pdf");
          }
```

what can be the problem?

Comment: Probably your antivirus opened the file automatically to scan it.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Maybe `MailMessage` keeps handle on the file for attachment? Could try throwing it into a using statement?

Comment: You also don't need to write the file. `Attachment` has a constructor for streams.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.attachment.-ctor?view=netcore-3.1#System_Net_Mail_Attachment__ctor_System_IO_Stream_System_Net_Mime_ContentType_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that you seem to be only writing these files to disk so that you can attach them to an email and then immediately delete them (and are encountering a problem with this), might I suggest that you instead don't write the files to disk at all, but instead write to a MemoryStream pair that you then seek to position 0 and use as the source of bytes for your attachments?

```
var imgMs = new MemoryStream();
bmp.Save(imgMS, ImageFormat.Png); //or whatever format


var pdfMs = new MemoryStream();
PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfdoc, pdfMs);


imgMs.Position = 0; //seek to start
Attachment attachmentImg = new Attachment(imgMs, "someimage.png", "image/png");
mail.Attachments.Add(attachmentImg);

pdfMs.Position = 0; //seek to start
Attachment attachmentPdf = new Attachment(pdfMs, "invoice.pdf", "application/pdf");
mail.Attachments.Add(attachmentPdf);
```

Note, I'm not really sure why you write the image to disk at all; you don't seem to attach it, only pass the bitmap directly into the PDF, so maybe you can skip the image streaming entirely

Comment: I saved the files locally initially for testing and then I forgot, I hadn't thought of this variant, thanks a lot! I tried to implement it, but even putting it in a using(), it keeps giving me error on the smtpclient.send saying "cannot access a closed stream"

Comment: I see your code has an `fs.Close()` in it from the time when you were trying to close the file stream so you could open another one when attaching. Did you directly swap that fs into being a memory stream; do you still have a call to close the memory stream somewhere? The mechanism you were trying before (to close the file stream and release the resources so you could successfully open another file stream) is probably now working against you..

Comment: right, I thought once I added the pdfdoc to the memorystream, it was not a problem to close pdfdoc and instead no, in fact now it works, the only problem is that in the email I receive there is the pdf file but it gives me that it is impossible to view it, as if was damaged

Comment: ok fixed also that problem, thanks so much for the help!

Comment: The research I did seemed to indicate that closing a pdf doc wouldn't close the underlying memorystream, but I suspect that closing the doc does write some necessary bytes to the stream so my guess would be to leave the memory stream open but close the pdf, and don't forget to seek the memory stream to position 0 (start) again

Answer (score -1):

You can try disposing Attachment and/or SmtpServer before deleting.

Answer (score -1):

The problem can be that you have opened the file that you want to delete and this causes a deadlock. Make sure that you are not using this file in any kind of way.